# Nodemailer SMTP Timeout Error from using ZOHO Mail Service?

Tags: node.js, express, email, smtp, nodemailer

I am using ZOHO mail as my email service with Nodemailer to send emails from a web app still in development. I have used the service for a while without it ever breaking and then this morning, i was testing the app, it wasn't sending out the emails and i started to get the timeout **error message:**

[image]

```
node:internal/errors:464
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error: queryA ETIMEOUT smtp.zoho.com
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:dns:213:19) {
errno: undefined,
code: 'EDNS',
syscall: 'queryA',
hostname: 'smtp.zoho.com',
command: 'CONN'
}
```

Below is the controller

```
module.exports.mailTest = function(user) {
log(user);
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'zoho',
    auth: {
        user: mailUser,
        pass: mailPass
    }
});
let userFirstName = user.name.split(' ')[0];
let mailOptions = {
    from: mailUser,
    to: user.email,
    subject: `Mail Check`,
    html: `<h2>Hi ${userFirstName}, Test Message</h2>`
}
try {
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    log('mail sent!');
}
  catch(err) {
      log(err);
      throw err;
  }
}
```

What does the error really mean and do i have to fix it from my end or is it really a problem with the smtp host?